# How do I make items optional in <xs:all>?

Tags: xsd

I have such xsd. These all fields can exist or not and in unpredictable order.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="request">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:all  minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element ref="field1"/>
    <xs:element ref="field2"/>
    <xs:element ref="field3"/>
    <xs:element ref="field4"/>
    <xs:element ref="field5"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

field4 doesn't exist in xml and validator says that he is waiting for field4, but he shouldn't say this. So what is wrong?

[w3cschools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_all.asp) says

```
<xs:element name="person">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:all minOccurs="0">
  <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The example above indicates that the "firstname" and the "lastname" elements can appear in any order and each element CAN appear zero or one time!

Comment: Show us a link to that example.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_all.asp W3C sucks

Comment: w3schools stuff is bad, and often flat wrong. Ignore it. Show me a real example from w3.org, like the one I linked to.

Answer (score 17):

You need to put the `minOccurs` on the individual elements, not the `<xs:all>`, i.e.

```
<xs:all>
    <xs:element ref="field1" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="field2" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="field3" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="field4" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="field5" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:all>
```

Putting `minOccurs="0"` on the `<xs:all>` is saying that entire group may be omitted, not individual elements.

See [XML Schema docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref18).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. Yep, now it works. Thanks again

Comment: @Shikarn-O: What is that comment meant to mean?

Answer (score 3):

try like this in all

```
 <xs:element ref="field4" minOccurs="0" >
```