# Cant get child elements of a set atmost once in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following schema-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="Type">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:choice  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:element name="First">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5">
        <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="c" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="d" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="Second" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
</xsd:choice>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

The pattern that I want to generate is that XML can contain First and Second elements any number of times and any order but element First should have child elements occurred at most once. i.e, a,b,c,d,e can occur at most once. I am not able to achieve this second part where child elements occur at most once. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `xsd:choice`, use `xsd:all` that allows elements to appear in any order. With the occurrence facets below each child element can appear either once or not at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="Type">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:choice  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="First">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:all maxOccurs="1">
                                <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xsd:element name="c" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xsd:element name="d" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xsd:all>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>

                    <xsd:element name="Second" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
                </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Validating against this schema, a document like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Type xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Untitled7.xsd">
    <First>
        <b>10</b>
        <a>10.0</a>
        <c>3</c>
        <d>4</d>
        <e>5</e>
    </First>
    <Second></Second>
</Type>
```

is valid, while the following would not be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Type xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Untitled7.xsd">
    <First>
        <b>10</b>
        <a>10.0</a>
        <c>3</c>
        <d>4</d>
        <e>5</e>
        <a>10.0</a>
    </First>
    <Second></Second>
</Type>
```

because `a` appears twice in the same `First` element.

Comment: @raghav Please do not post code in comments - it's unreadable. And I do not understand your comment. What are you trying to tell me? Just try using the schema I have suggested.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks. I want to add that I am able to generate the "invalid" XML posted by you with my original schema. Aren't occurrence facets working with child elements?

Comment: Muller //With the occurrence facets below each child element can appear either once or not at all// That is the requirement. Hence I wrote "at most once". Why would occurrence facet not work with child elements?

Comment: Your schema does not fit my requirement. I want child elements to occur at most once. Whereas your schema forces child element to occur exactly once.

Comment: @raghav Yes, you are right, I have edited my answer - now, `minOccurs` should apply to every child element individually.

Comment: Still not correct. Your schema still requires each child element to be present exactly once. I repeat, I want child elements at most once NOT exactly once. That is the problem. Occurrence facet is not working with child elements in your schema too. Hope you get it. Thanks.

Comment: @raghav "Your schema still requires each child element to be present exactly once. " No, that's not true. A document where, for instance, `a` is missing is **valid**. Here is another answer saying the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5677219/1987598. No need to be rude. What tool or library are you using to perform the validation? What version of XML Schema?

Comment: I am not being rude. I am sorry if it seemed so. May be its my English. Sorry again. Ya you are right. I forgot to remove minOccurs from <xsd:all>. Thanks for your patience and sorry again. Hope you don't mind my English.

Comment: @raghav No worries. If this answer is correct now, can I ask you to accept it? Here is how accepting answers works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Some of your previous questions also have answers that you have not accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I am working with XML 1.0 doing online validation from a website. Also I got my original schema working with <xsd:all maxOccurs="1"> replaced by <xsd:choice maxOccurs="5"> rest being the same as suggested by you. Thanks.