# PHP SOAP-ERROR: object has no 'test2' property

Tags: php, xml, wsdl, soap-client

I have the following xml from part of an auto generated web service wsdl:

```
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="test">
     <xs:element name="test">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="txt" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
           </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="test2">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="txt" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
           </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="request_box">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:all minOccurs="0">
              <xs:element ref="ns0:test"/>
              <xs:element ref="ns0:test2"/>
           </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

when I do a soap call from php:

```
  $xml = "test.xml";
  $params = array(
    'test' => array(
      'txt' =>  $txt
    )
  );
  try {
    $client = new SoapClient($xml);
    $test = $client->request_box($params);
  } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    var_dump($fault);
  }
```

I get this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'test2' property
```

If I change `$params` and add `test2` to it then I dont get any erros:

```
  $params = array(
    'test' => array(
      'txt' =>  $txt
    ),
    'test2' => array(
      'txt' =>  $txt
    )
  );
```

But I want `test2` to be optional.

If I change xml and add `minOccurs="0"` to `test2` the problem will be solved and I dont get any errors anymore:

```
 <xs:element name="request_box">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:all minOccurs="0">
          <xs:element ref="ns0:test"/>
          <xs:element ref="ns0:test2" minOccurs="0"/>
       </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

But should't all the child elements (here `test` and `test2`) already inherit `minOccurs="0"` from the parent `<xs:all minOccurs="0">` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:all minOccurs="0">
```

The xs:all minOccurs is for the whole group, not for elements. So the behavior you are experiencing is correct.

**General suggestion:** Use some tool (like SOAPUI, Altova XML Spy(paid)) to validate the XML before testing from a programming language. It will save a lot of time.

**Similar question:** [How do I make items optional in <xs:all>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677154/how-do-i-make-items-optional-in-xsall)